# Buttons on form1 will change amount of something in form2

Tags: c#, forms

I am creating an application, and I want to make different difficulty levels.
is there a way to change the amount of something in form2 when clicking 1 of the 3 buttons in form1.

like

```
_multiplicand = randomizer.Next(2, 11);_
```

when you click on button 1 on form1, the amount of form 2 needs to be (2, 11);
when you click on button 2 on form1, the amount of form 2 needs to be (10, 21)
and when you click on button 3 on form1, the amount of form 2 needs to be (20, 101);

I know you can duplicate form1 2 times and change the amount in each form and just connect the buttons to the other forms (form3,form4), but that will make the application larger.

Comment: You can add a method to your second form class that makes the desired changes, and invoke this method from your first form.

Comment: Is form2 opened from form1? If form1 have the form2 instance varaible, just create a public function in form2 with which yo can do this requirement. Or else make the form instances global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to `form2` inside your `form1` and then "submit" the new value to it:

Something like:

```
Form2 form2;

void Init()
{
    form2 = new Form2(); // or however you create form2
}

void OnButtonClicked()
{
    var newValue = GetNewValue();
    form2.CurrentValue = newValue;
}
```

and inside `Form2` something like:

```
public int CurrentValue { get; set; }
```

Note: This is not working code - it just should give you an idea how to solve such a problem.